# SQL Server - TSQL: cumulative count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have the following query:

```
Select Year(DATEADD(MONTH,3,date)) as Year, Month(DATEADD(MONTH,3,date)) as Month, location, COUNT (agent_login_id)
from Agents
where Location = 'syd'
Group by Location, Year(DATEADD(MONTH,3,date)), Month(DATEADD(MONTH,3,date))
```

it outputs:

```
Year    Month   location    Count

2013    1   SYD 1
2013    3   SYD 11
2013    4   SYD 2
2013    5   SYD 2
2013    8   SYD 3
2013    9   SYD 1
2013    10  SYD 4
2013    11  SYD 7
2013    12  SYD 7
2014    1   SYD 3
2014    2   SYD 1
```

But I need to do a cumulative count so for example this is what I need it to look like

```
 Year   Month   location    Count Cumulative count
 2013   1   SYD 1           1
 2013   3   SYD 11          12
 2013   4   SYD 2           14
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Version of SQL Server?

Comment: Dont u mean 14 as last number?

Comment: version is 2008 r2 - and the number should be 14 your right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `@t` to represent your current query

For what I'll call 'full accumulation' (based on original question)

```
-- 2012
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l ORDER BY y, m)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT y, m, c, ISNULL(a + LAG(a,2) OVER(PARTITION BY l ORDER BY y, m), a) a
FROM (
    SELECT t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c, SUM(t2.c) a
    FROM t t1
    JOIN t t2 ON t2.rn <= t1.rn AND t2.l = t1.l
    GROUP BY t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c
) t

-- 2005+
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l ORDER BY y, m)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c, ISNULL(SUM(t2.c)+SUM(t3.c), MIN(t1.c)) a
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON t2.rn <= t1.rn AND t2.l = t1.l
LEFT JOIN t t3 ON t3.rn < t2.rn-1
GROUP BY t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c
```

**Edit**

For a normal running total (after question was corrected)

```
--2005+
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l ORDER BY y, m)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c, SUM(t2.c) a
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON t2.rn <= t1.rn AND t2.l = t1.l
GROUP BY t1.y, t1.l, t1.m, t1.c
```

Note: If in your current query you calculated the first day of the month instead of using `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` (leaving these calculations to the end if required) then you could avoid using `ROW_NUMBER()` which may see some performance improvements